# app[worker.1]: bash: *.py: command not found

Tags: python, heroku

Background:
I made a discord bot witch parse web page for me 1 time in 10minutes and send me in discord chat (with BeautifulSoup4 and  requests)
I tryed to deploy it on Heroku. It was successful but i had log error "at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/". i solved it with "heroku ps:scale web=1".
Now i have this log:

```
2021-06-06T19:17:15.814890+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to worker@1:Free by user alexpenguinqq@gmail.com
2021-06-06T19:17:19.492130+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `main.py`
2021-06-06T19:17:20.174553+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-06T19:17:21.540882+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-06-06T19:17:21.489291+00:00 app[worker.1]: bash: main.py: command not found
2021-06-06T19:17:21.659522+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-06-06T19:17:21.669696+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-06T19:17:25.330503+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `main.py`
2021-06-06T19:17:26.015033+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-06T19:17:27.602622+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-06-06T19:17:27.668623+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-06-06T19:17:27.551896+00:00 app[worker.1]: bash: main.py: command not found
```

how can i solve this problem?

my requirements:

```
discord.py==1.7.2
requests==2.25.1
BeautifulSoup4==4.9.3
websockets==9.1
```

my procfile:
`worker: main.py`

simplified version of main.py:

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import discord
client = discord.Client()
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        return get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('error')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    parsing_disc.start()
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@tasks.loop(minutes = 10)
async def parsing_disc():
    global NumberC
    global NameP
    NumberC = 0
    EnyMsg = ''
    print('try to parse...')
    while NumberC <= 22:
        EnyMsg = parse()
        if EnyMsg:
            f = open('player_base.txt')
            text = f.read()
            if NameP in text:
                print('Уже было')
            else:
                f = open('player_base.txt', 'a')
                f.write('\n' + NameP)
                channel = client.get_channel(846420270621523971)
                await channel.send('```' + EnyMsg + '```' + '\n' + CharURL)
            f.close()
        NumberC += 1
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with setting your worker variable. `main.py` is not an actual command but the `.py` file you are trying to run.

Instead, try setting `worker` to

```
worker: python main.py
```

Comment: app[worker.1]: python: can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/` in `/app/main.py`?

Comment: i haven't ```/``` in my proc file it is new log after i add ```worker: python main.py```

Comment: i have only one directory https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W5F6.png

Comment: Oh, it looks like your `main.py` is capitalized. So, try `worker: python Main.py`